# exponential regression with R ( and negative values)

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to fit a curve to a set of data points but did not succeed. So I ask you.

```
plot(time,val) # look at data 
exponential.model <- lm(log(val)~ a) # compute model
fit <- exp(predict(exponential.model,list(Time=time))) # create the fitted curve
plot(time,val)#plot it again
lines(time, fit,lwd=2) # show the fitted line
```

My only problem is, that my data contains negative values and so log(val) produces a lot of NA making the model computation crash. [image: My Data] 
I know that my data does not necessarily look like exponential , but I want to see the fit anyway. I also used another program which shows me val=27.1331*exp(-time/2.88031)  is a nice fit but I do not know, what I am doing wrong.
 I want to compute it with R.
I had the idea to shift data so no negative values remain, but result is poor and quite sure wrong.

```
plot(time,val+20) # look at data 
exponential.model <- lm(log(val+20)~ a) # compute model
fit <- exp(predict(exponential.model,list(Time=time))) # create the fitted curve
plot(time,val)#plot it again
lines(time, fit-20,lwd=2) # show the (BAD) fitted line
```

[image: My data with bad (shift)-fit]

Thank you!

Comment: I think you're trying to fit a round peg through a square hole. That's obviously a terrible model for the data. any exponential model will be. There's obviously a periodic component there and lots of autocorrelation that you should try to capture and the model you're trying to fit won't capture either.

Comment: I know, that data looks not like an exponetial model but it should be possible to fit it anyway. As I said, val=27.1331*exp(-time/2.88031), is a fine fit for me. If I could get that result, I would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I figured some things out and have a satisfying solution.

```
exponential.model <- lm(log(val)~ a) # compute model
```

The log(val) term is trying to rescale the values, so a linear model can be applied. Since this not possible to my values, you have to use a non-linear model (nls).

```
  exponential.model <- nls(val ~ a*exp(b*time), start=c(b=-0.1,h=30))
```

This worked fine for me.
[satisfying fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5QRR.png)